# Does "the town has reasons to be chosen" make sense or sound natural?

Tags: meaning, expressions

In a competition to choose the site of a big regional event, a particular town stands out with a sufficient number of hotels, a wonderful environment, hospitality and other advantages. If I say, "The town has reasons to be chosen," does it make sense and/or sound natural?    I wondered if the sentence may imply that the town is insisiting to be chosen as the site.

Comment: What is it about the sentence that makes you question its fluency?

Comment: Wondered if the sentence is gramatically correct and may imply that the town is insisiting to be chosen as the site. Thank you

Comment: That's good - editing that comment into your question would improve the question. As for the sense of the sentence, yes, it's ambiguous - it could be considered a figure of speech such as anthropomorphism, or it could be taken as the simple reading. The sentence conveys the intended meaning so 'makes sense' in that respect, but InternetHobo's answer has a much more *natural* sounding rendition.

Answer (score 5):

"There are reasons to choose the town." is probably better. It expresses that the reasons to choose the town exist, instead of implying that the town itself it actively trying to be chosen.